# Qt: как сделать чтобы форма открывалась внутри приложения, а не как новое окно

Tags: c++, qt

Например, как в Excel [скрин 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GeLQ.jpg), [скрин 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANs4U.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте виджету указать тип окна **Qt::Tool** ([перечисление Qt::WindowType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum)).

Это можно сделать, например, через метод [setWindowFlag](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setWindowFlag)